# Can I install water filters in parallel to abate pressure loss?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, water-filtration

I'm considering adding a whole house filtration system. I know these have flow limits and cost pressure.

If I installed two in parallel would that abate the pressure and flow drops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 filters in parallel will reduce pressure drop because of the increased area allowing higher flow but the cost of 2 filters , housings etc may be much more than a larger single filter. I have installed filters in parallel in the past but have found it to be cheaper to purchase a larger single filter.